# .net core possible missing references, application port

Tags: .net-core

I am porting a web application to .NET core. I created a new MVC Web application, then added a Class Library (Package). I wired in my Telerik stuff and tested a skeleton deploy to the web server. So far so good.
I copied my code (classes) to the Library project. 
Currently I am getting errors on a number of lines of code. For example:

```
'StringComparison' does not contain a definition for InvariantCultureIgnoreCase'
```

I'm guessing due to modularity of .NET core, I need to include some sort of library using Nuget to include the fuctionality.

My project.json is as follows:

```
"frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Common.Logging": "3.3.1",
        "NHibernate": "4.0.4.4000"
      }
    },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
```

Is there some sort of resource listing the avalable packages and the functionality they provide?

Possibly there are bigger issues for what I am trying to accomplish. As I am also getting errors on my Common.Logging e.g.:

```
The name 'LogManager' does not exist in the current context
```

The references are included in the .cs files, however the issue still exists. Is this due to competing frameworks of net451 and donet5.4?

Comment: You'll have to deal with stuff not being supported in .NETCore.  A framework version whose original goal was to be small.  Nothing very small about StringComparison. an innocent looking enum that has massive character property tables underneath to get it implemented.  No tables for InvariantCulture included.

Comment: OK, so I would still like to use MVC 6. Is it possible to just remove the dotnet5.4 framework in all the projects and focus on dnx451 or 452? Will I also need to change the global.json "sdk: version : "1.0.0.0-rc1-update"